# Eclipse: make curly bracket more noticeable

Tags: java, eclipse

I am using Eclipse. You see this ending curly bracket next to `catch(FileNotFoundException fne) {`:

[image]

How do I make it more noticeable when I select on starting curly brackets so I can clearly see where it ends?

Comment: Actually, it's a brace:

[] = brackets
() = parentheses
{} = braces

Answer (score 66, accepted):

From `Window > Preferences`, go to `Java > Editor` and Select `Matching brackets highlight` and pick a color that will stand out and also make sure Highlight matching brackets is checked :)

[image]

I changed mine to red and this is what it looks like now.(and I did not have to restart eclipse)

[image]

Comment: I did not have to restart eclipse. Make sure Highlight matching brackets is checked :)

Comment: @Jahkr : What else do you want ? I think BalaR has rightly provided with the solution. +1 from me. :)

Comment: Yes it works... but I don't see the new color option. My only solution: Stop using Vista. :| Thanks.

Comment: For me, the highlight was checked by default when I installed eclipse. It was not highlighting for me though. When I changed the color to red and then restarted it started working.

Comment: uncheck the highlighting, apply, check it again, apply, worked for me

Comment: Unchecking and rechecking works for me too, but any idea why this randomly turns off, and fairly frequently?  I am using Eclipse EE for Web Developers, Juno Service Release 2.

Answer (score 3):

In newer versions (mine is 4.2.1 installed with ADT) you can also select the type of Bracket highlighting to:

- Matching bracket - you must have cursor right next to the bracket and it will highlight only the corresponding bracket
- Matching bracket and caret location - same as matching bracket, only it will highlight both brackets
- Enclosing brackets - highlight both brackets that enclosing the place where your cursor is located

For my, I prefer Enclosing brackets for better orientation in general with red color as Bala R has shown.

Answer (score 2):

Many thanks for tips. Indeed these are helpful. I also find following a convenient way to see how brackets can be matched. if you just want to see where the matching bracket is, use ctrl+shift+p to navigate to the matching bracket.
This is especially helpful for those who have used "vi" editor a lot and were used to "%" feature of "vi" to match brackets.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me . Go to **Window>Preferences>General>Editors>Structured Text Editors** . Select appropriate color and you are good to go.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For Eclipse IDE Version 2022-06.

- Windows and Linux: **Window > Preferences > Java > Editor**
- Mac: **Eclipse > Preferences > Java > Editor**

[image]