# How to change matching bracket highlight in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse

Eclipse draws a rectangular box around the bracket that matches the bracket next to your cursor, like this:

[image]

Is it possible to change the style of the highlighted bracket, so that it looks like this instead:

[image]

I would think this would be rather easy, but so far I have not been able to find out how to do it.

Comment: This may not what you desire, but it provides some configuration: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5925473/8229192

Comment: @FullStackDeveloper as you mentioned, not quite what I want.

Comment: The color of the box is the only thing supported for this.

Comment: @greg-449 do you know if there is a way to make it so that the cursor still shows up if it is to the left of a matching bracket?